How can i adding Google-Translate to my web page?
I want to add google translate for my website which supports all countries of the world. so that I can make it look the way I want (editable and customizable) (html, css, js)
I don't know where to start, I tried so many ways, but none of them were customizable or I didn't know how.

You can use this:
https://github.com/mordadam/google-translate-html-js
